# How to access dynamically created GTK Checkbutton in plain C

Tags: c, checkbox, dynamic, gtk3, children

I created a program that outputs CSV formatted tags based on checkbuttons..  There's a LOT of them so it only makes sense to create them programmatically..  I was successful in that sense, but I was never able to figure out how to get their checked state since you can't access them like normal checkbuttons.  I worked around it, but now getting to the 'polishing' phase of my program, I'd REALLY like to be able to reset the form by unchecking them all, and I can't figure out how to access them..  First, here's how the checkbuttons are created dynamically:

```
        for (int x = 0; x <= NUMBER_OF_STRING; x++)
        {
            if (tagArray[x] != NULL && strcmp(tagArray[x], "\0"))
            {
                dynamic_checkBox = gtk_check_button_new_with_label(tagArray[x]);
                gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(flowBox), dynamic_checkBox);
                g_signal_connect(dynamic_checkBox, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(check_state), (gpointer)tagArray[x]);
            }
        }
```

So that works just fine..  I was able to use a little 'hack' creating an extra char array and putting 'true' or 'false' strings in there and using strcmp() to basically write my own checked/unchecked state to an array with the gpointer data, but as with most hacks, if you're not doing it right it comes back to get ya..  Now I can't figure out how to uncheck all the boxes and reset the form..

```
static void uncheck_button_clicked(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(dynamic_checkBox), FALSE);
}
```

As you can see, I'm calling the global GtkWidget *dynamic_checkBox but that doesn't help me because it doesn't point to the actual instance of that checkbutton I need..  So how do I go about accessing these checkboxes?  I even tried dynamically declaring new GtkWidgets with strings so I could access them, but it just lead to incompatible type errors... I've been Googling and banging my head against the wall for 2 days now with no results.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you probably need is [GtkCellRendereToggle](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererToggle.html). Any way, please edit your Question with an example code.

Comment: How about placing all CheckBoxes into a hash table with tagArray[x] as key? When you want to uncheck all of them just iterate over the hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make sense to use a global `GtkWidget*` or `GtkCheckButton*`, since you have multiple of them anyway, so each time you create a new one, it will overwrite the old value.

Next, there are 2 ways of still accessing those buttons:

- Like Alexander suggested in the comments, you can keep a list of `GtkWidget*` or `GtkCheckButton*` (and add your buttons as you create them on the go). That way, you can iterate over the array and uncheck them all.
- Another option is to use the parent container of all the check buttons, by iterating over its children (but that really assumes you don't have any other GtkCheckButtons in there!)

```c
GList *children = gtk_container_get_children (GTK_CONTAINER (flowbox));
for (GList *l = children; l; m = g_list_next (l)) {
    GtkWidget *child = l->data;

    // Note, you don't need this if-check if your flowbox only contains checkbuttons.
    // Bote 2: this *will* turn off also unrelated check buttons
    if (GTK_IS_CHECK_BUTTON (child)) {
        gtk_toggle_button_set_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (child), FALSE);
    }
}
```

As a side remark: you can use `strcmp(tagArray[x], "")` if you just want to check if the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  Thank you all for your responses.  Everyone's contributions helped and were researched, but it was a combination of Alexander's comment and the chosen answer that were what helped me.  I didn't think lists existed in C.  Only arrays..  Good to know GTK offers a GList..

Anyways..  after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, (this is literally my 5th day trying to learn low-level C, I'm a C# guy) I was able to modify the provided answer to fit my solution.

Step 1:  Add the checkbuttons to a list so they can be retrieved later.  Only one line was added to the existing code:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= NUMBER_OF_STRING; x++)
{
    if (tagArray[x] != NULL && strcmp(tagArray[x], "\0"))
    {
        dynamic_checkBox = gtk_check_button_new_with_label(tagArray[x]);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(flowBox), dynamic_checkBox);
        g_signal_connect(dynamic_checkBox, "toggled" G_CALLBACK(check_state), (gpointer)tagArray[x]);
        checkButtonList = g_list_insert(checkButtonList, dynamic_checkBox, -1);
    }
}
```

Step 2:  Iterate through the list of checkbuttons and uncheck each one:

```
static void uncheck_button_clicked(GtkCheckButton* checkButton, gpointer data)
{

     for (GList *l = checkButtonList; l != NULL; l = l->next)
    {
        GtkWidget *child = l->data;
        gtk_toggle_button_set_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(child), FALSE);
    }
    
}
```